# React - Component Full Screen (with height 100%)

Tags: css, reactjs, html

I'm stuck with displaying a React component named "home" that take 100% of the height of my screen.
Whatever I use CSS or React inline style it doesn't work.

In the example below, **html**, **body** and **#app** are set to  height: 100% in CSS. For **.home** I used inline style (but whatever I used CSS or inline style is the same):
[image]
The issue seems to come from `<div data-reactroot data-reactid='1'>` that is not set with height: 100%.

If I hacked it with Chrome developer tool, it's work:
[image]

So what is the proper way to display a full height component in React ?

Any help is welcome :)

Comment: Your component `<MyComponent ...>` is what is creating this div with a reactid. So you need add either a class or style to it. e.g. `<MyComponent className="full-height">`

Comment: Thanks a lot you were right, I just forgot an upper component..!

Answer (score 93):

```
html, body, #app, #app>div {
  height: 100%
}
```

This will ensure all the chain to be `height: 100%`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: @Dev-iL rather telling what it should be done, why not do what it should be done.

Comment: setting the values for `html` and `body` are necessary because `100%` will follow the the "closest" parent that specified the dimension explicitly. Which means if both `html` and `body` have unspecified `height`, children with `height: 100%` has no effect.

Comment: Which css file should this be added to?

Comment: You should add this to index.css, also don't forget to change "app" name.

Comment: @AlexanderSantos  what is this `app` name? where can I find the name? sorry I'm very new to frontend dev

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C i think it was about the `#app` selector, it can be another id

Answer (score 61):

You could also do:

```
body > #root > div {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case I missed passing height through #root

Answer (score 37):

try `<div style = {{height:"100vh"}}> </div>`

Comment: I'm using this solution because it doesn't affect the parent elements (html, body etc.). Is there any disadvantage?

Comment: This works for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 23):

It annoys me for days. And finally I make use of the CSS property selector to solve it.

```
[data-reactroot] 
        {height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Should the accepted answer. To be sure add : `position: absolute;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;`

Comment: This works, but can cause problems with other components. There needs to be a more "correct" way of doing this.

Comment: Where did you add this though?

Answer (score 18):

Despite using of React here - elements layout is completely html/css feature.

The root cause of the issue is in how `height` property in css works. When you are using relative values for height (in %) - this means that height will be set in relation to its parent.

So if you have a structure like `html > body > div#root > div.app` - to make `div.app` 100% height **all its ancestors** should have 100% height. You may play with next example:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

div#root {
  height: 100%; /* remove this line to see div.app is no more 100% height */
  background-color: indigo;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

div.app {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: cornsilk;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="app"> I will be 100% height if my parents are </div>
</div>
```

Few arguments:

- Usage of `!important` - despite some time this feature is useful in ~95% of cases, it indicates a poor structure of html/css. Also, this is not a solution to the current problem.
- Why not `position: absolute`. Property `positon` is designed to change how the element will be rendered in relation to (own position - relative, viewport - fixed, nearest parent whos position is not static - absolute). Ans despite `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;` will result in the same look - it also pushes you to change parents `position` to something not `static` - so you need to maintain 2 elements. That also causes parent div be collapsed in a line (0-height), and inner - full screen. That makes confusion in element inspector.

Comment: This was actually helpful! I didn't know you have to go all the way setting 100% in every important element. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I managed this with a css class in my app.css

```
.fill-window {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Apply it to your root element in your render() method

```
render() {
   return ( <div className="fill-window">{content}</div> );
}
```

Or inline

```
render() {
   return (
      <div style={{ height: '100%', position: 'absolute', left: '0px', width: '100%', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
          {content}
      </div>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
#app {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Always full height of view min

Comment: min-height will overwrite height

Answer (score 7):

While this may not be the ideal answer but try this:

```
style={{top:'0', bottom:'0', left:'0', right:'0', position: 'absolute'}}
```

It keeps the size attached to borders which is not what you want but gives you somewhat same effect.

Answer (score 6):

```
body{
  height:100%
}

#app div{
  height:100%
}
```

this works for me..

Comment: This will make **all divs** anywhere below `#app` have height 100%. You may want to use `#app>div`, selecting only immediate child divs of `#app`

Answer (score 6):

```
<div style={{ height: "100vh", background: "#2d405f" }}>
   <Component 1 />
   <Component 2 />
</div>
```

Create a div with full screen with background color #2d405f

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue displaying my side navigation panel height to 100%.

My steps to fix it was to:

In the index.css file ------

```
.html {
   height: 100%;
}
.body {
   height:100%;
}
```

In the sidePanel.css (this was giving me issues):

```
.side-panel {
   height: 100%;
   position: fixed; <--- this is what made the difference and scaled to 100% correctly
}
```

Other attributes were taken out for clarity, but I think the issue lies with scaling the height to 100% in nested containers like how you are trying to scale height in your nested containers. The parent classes height will need to be applied the 100%. - What i'm curious about is why fixed: position corrects the scale and fails without it; this is something i'll learn eventually with some more practice.

I've been working with react for a week now and i'm a novice to web developing, but I wanted to share a fix that I discovered with scaling height to 100%; I hope this helps you or anyone who has a similar issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Try it to solve your problem

```html
<div style = {{height:"100vh"}}> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a project using CRNA i use this
in `index.css`

```
html, body, #root {
  height: 100%;
}
```

and then in my App.css i use this

```
.App {
  height: 100%;
}
```

and also set height to 100% for a div within App if there is one eg-

```
.MainGridContainer {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this in the `index.html` head worked for me:

```
<style>
    html, body, #app, #app>div { position: absolute; width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important; }
</style>
```

Comment: !important should not be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble until i used the inspector and realized react puts everything inside a div with id='root' granting that 100% height along with body and html worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

CRA has a #root div to which we render our react app, so it should also be considered a parent div and give appropriate height according to your need. This answer is based on my experience with a similar situation and giving 100% height to #root helped me fix the height issue with one of it's child element.

This depends on the layout of your app, in my case the child was not able to takeup the given height because #root(parent) div had no specified height

Answer (score 0):

Funny how this works since I thought `html` was the one with not full height, turns out it was the `body`.

Just add the below `css` in `index.css`:

```
body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

There is an existing `body` tag? Add it in there!

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trouble shooting in NextJS 13 & Tailwind to achieve this.
There's an additional layer of < div>'s that I'm unable to locate generated from Next's new AppDir.

One way to trouble shoot that nobody mentioned, which is easy to overlook is:

Open your Web Dev Tools and modify each ancestor to height:100% or in Tailwind 'h-full' and you'll save time to see if height full is the appropriate solution for your use case. I was quickly able to find out my footer component overlaps my div with this method instead of wasting time.

Edit: Reason for Next 13 user https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42345

Answer (score -2):

try using !important in height. It is probably because of some other style affecting your html body.

```
{ height : 100% !important; }
```

also you can give values in VP which will set height to viee port pixel you mention like`height : 700vp;` but this wont be portable.

Comment: Using `important` in most cases is an indicator of a poor solution. The problem is in how height behaves in nested elements.