# CSS 100% height not working in React app

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to use Flexbox in my React app to create a simple two column webpage that occupies the full width and height.

I can get this to work with HTML and CSS on their own but not within a React app.

So far I have:

```
:root {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%
}

.flexbox {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  height: 100%
}

.right {
  flex: 1
}
```

and:

```
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="left">
    Left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Right
  </div>
</div>
```

I realise that I need to account for the additional `<div id="root"></div>` tag in my `index.html` so I have also added the following to my css:

```
#root {
  height: 100%;
}
```

And my `render` function:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="flexbox">
      <div className="left">Left</div>
      <div className="right">Right</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

but this doesn't work. The columns exist but are not full height. Why not?

Comment: Forgive me if I sound stupid, but you are importing your css file right ?

Comment: Yes I am.`left` and `right` actually have background colours and they are showing.

Comment: you can refer this link:-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height

Comment: this has nothing to do with react, only css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - Component Full Screen (with height 100%)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428322/react-component-full-screen-with-height-100)

Answer (score 39):

If you use `create-react-app`, it adds an element with `class=App` and an element with `id=root` to the DOM. They should also get `height: 100%`

```
html, body, #root, .App {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Amazing. Spent 3 days on this issue!! This did it for me!

Comment: `#root` did it!

Comment: Man I hate CRA!

Comment: This AND making sure to import my css into the component helped me

Answer (score 11):

Use viewport height units in css:

```
#root {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: I really want to understand why my code doesn't work in the React app???

Comment: It really doesn't? It should work, you can try to set `min-height: 100vh;` on your `flexbox` class instead. It works for me, maybe something overwrites your css?

Comment: This will cause excess height on mobile due to the way VH is calculated.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot that `<html>` is also a tag. Moreover, it is parent to all parents! That's why you should give it height of 100% as well.

`html, body {
  height: 100%;
}`

Comment: `:root` is the same as `html`

Answer (score 4):

The body looks to its parent (HTML) for how to scale the dynamic property, so the HTML element needs to have its height set as well.

However, the content of the body will probably need to change dynamically. Setting min-height to 100% will accomplish this goal.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `html` does have a height - see `:root`

Comment: Remember - this does work outside of React (HTML and CSS)

Comment: check my lastest edit. min-height: -> height. it's work fine to me.

Comment: you can read this post which explain very clear about min-height. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8468131/6600081

Answer (score 1):

To the parent div of the page, add the following css.

```
position: fixed;
overflow: auto;
height: 100vh;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
[data-reactroot] 
        {height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if anything suggested above doesn't seems to be working for some reason, try using normalize.css package. It wipes all browser provided CSS and creates a fresh window for the app.

```
   "normalize.css": "^8.0.1" //package.json (yarn add or npm install)
   import "normalize.css/normalize.css"; //in app.js
```

Then in css file define the body height and width as 100vh & 100vw respectively.

docs: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of answers here but none of them is working. I have tested all of them.
The best way to achieve minimum height in react js is to use the main tag inside your app and then add the minimum height for that tag.

Your App.js code should look like this.

```
<React.Fragment>
            <Header />
            <main>
                <Container>

                </Container>
            </main>
            <Footer />
</React.Fragment>
```

**Note**
You can simply remove React.Fragment if you want to use empty fragments.
then your code should look like this.

```
<>
    <Header />
    <main>

    //Write your code here

    </main>
    <Footer />
</>
```

Now add CSS to your CSS file.

```
main {
    min-height: 80vh;
}
```

**Important**
Few things you have to keep in mind.
Your header and footer or component call should be outside of the main tag. Like the code, I have shared above. I have called the header and footer outside the  tag.
If you want to use routing then simply add Router above the  tag.
Your code with routing and components call should look like this.

```
<React.Fragment>
            <Router>
                <Header />
                <main>
                    <Container>
                        <Route path='/' component={HomeScreen} exact />
                        <Route path='/products' component={ProductScreen} />
                        <Route path='/cart' component={CartScreen} />
                        <Route path='/login' component={LoginScreen} />
                    </Container>
                </main>
                <Footer />
            </Router>
        </React.Fragment>
```