# React native flex issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-navigation

I am trying to setup my child component with simple view as follow:

```
  render() {
    console.log("in render")
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}>
        <Text>hello</Text>
      </View>
```

It dosnt display anything. If I remove the flex it show the "hello" text with the background color as specified. what have I done wrong?

I also using navigator... maybe I need to setup something in navigator to display the view with flex?

Comment: This likely will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428322/react-component-full-screen-with-height-100

Comment: can you share the style for your parent-component ?

Comment: i had the same issue, inspired by @MahmoudAbdALKareem i put flex 1 to the parent-component and it worked.
thanks MahmoudAbdALKareem

Comment: I'm glad to help you !

Answer (score 1):

Try adding width: '100%' to the view style.